# Missing entries if order of entries is changed

Tags: entries, order

I'm having a very bizarre problem and was wondering if anyone else has had this happen. I have a page displaying thumbnails of product sheets.

My loop code starts with this:

`{% for entry in craft.entries.section('resources').order('title asc') if entry.industry.label == "Healthcare" and entry.documentType.label == "Product Sheet" %}`

If I leave it like this, I am missing the last three entries alphabetically (they start with V, W and Z).

If I change it to be descending order by title instead of ascending, I get all but one entry.

And if I change the order to be based on a field I have called lastUpdated, it will show all of the entries.

With the above loop code, if I change the names of the missing three entries to have earlier letters in front of them (i.e. changing Value Care to AValue Care), all entries will appear and no additional entries will fall off.

This is such a strange problem, and I feel like I'm crazy. Has anyone else seen something like this happen?

Comment: That sounds really weird. Just checking, what happens when you add a `limit(null)` parameter to your query, i.e. `{% for entry in craft.entries.section('resources').order('title asc').limit(null) %}`?

Comment: @MatsMikkelRummelhoff was thinking the same thing.

Comment: @MatsMikkelRummelhoff – That worked. Thank you! So weird that's needed, since it will show all of them without it with the different order parameters, and since there are only a total of about 15 entries. Thanks again for a solution!